# Union beween existing family members in genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

I would like to draw a family tree using the `genealogytree` package.

How do I make a `union` between two `child` already in the tree, at different places? The two "Daughter" in the image below are actually the same person. I would like for her to be both her parents' daughter and her husband's wife.

Is there a solution to make a call to `id=daughter` to bring the already created `child` into `union`?

[image: Family tree]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=formal graph]{
            child{
                g[male]{\text{Father}}
                p[female]{\text{Mother}}
                child{
                    g{\text{Many generations}}
                    child[id=familySon]{
                        g[male]{\text{Son}}
                        p[id=daughter,female]{\text{Daughter}}
                    }       
                }
                child{
                    g{\text{Many more generations}}
                    c[id=daughter,female]{\text{Daughter}}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting options for `genealogytree` a parent can be added to a family created in this tree if the parent already exists (from a previous tree) or is created in that same tree.

Options to pass to `genealogytree`:

```
add parent=daughter to familySon
```

and remove the second "Daughter" created in `familySon`, keeping only the one in her parents family.

[image: Family tree]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=formal graph,
        add parent=daughter to familySon]{
            child{
                g[male]{\text{Father}}
                p[female]{\text{Mother}}
                child{
                    g{\text{Many generations}}
                    child[id=familySon]{
                        g[male]{\text{Son}}
                    }       
                }
                child{
                    g{\text{Many more generations}}
                    c[id=daughter,female]{\text{Daughter}}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```